# Why dd finishes instantly when pipelining to cat?

Tags: process, cygwin, dd

I start bash on Cygwin and type:

```
dd if=/dev/zero | cat /dev/null
```

It finishes instantly. When I type:

```
dd if=/dev/zero > /dev/null
```

it runs as expected and I can issue

```
killall -USR1 dd
```

to see the progress. Why does the former invocation finishes instantly? Is it the same on a Linux box?

*** Explanation why I asked such stupid question and possibly not so stupid question

I was compressing hdd images and some were compressed incorrectly. I ended up with the following script showing the problem:

```
while sleep 1 ; do killall -v -USR1 dd ; done &
dd if=/dev/zero bs=5000000 count=200 | gzip -c | gzip -cd |  wc -c
```

Wc should write 1000000000 at the end. The problem is that it does not on my machine:

```
bash-3.2$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=5000000 count=200 | gzip -c | gzip -cd |  wc -c
13+0 records in
12+0 records out
60000000 bytes (60 MB) copied, 0.834 s, 71.9 MB/s
27+0 records in
26+0 records out
130000000 bytes (130 MB) copied, 1.822 s, 71.4 MB/s
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
1000000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 13.231 s, 75.6 MB/s
1005856128
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong once again?

Comment: Ah, a nomination for the UUOC award; http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Thanks guys - from time to time everybody makes a mistake :) And thanks for the award :)

Comment: @TomO'Connor Working link: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any reason to do what you are trying to do but the following way is the one you are looking for i guess.

```
 dd if=/dev/zero | cat > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, you first command is not functionnal. You are trying to pipe the output of /dev/zero into a command that takes no input.

`cat /dev/null` is just a command that outputs nothing. Piping anything something in it will therefore do nothing at all.

When you use the stdout redirect, the output of /dev/zero gets written to the file in question (/dev/null therefore nowhere).

Answer (score 2):

What `dd if=/dev/zero | cat /dev/null` does is:

run `cat /dev/null` attach it's stdin to `dd` stdout. Problem is, that `/dev/null` is empty. So `cat` does what is asked to do:
open empty file write it contents to stdout and finish.

`cat` does pipe output from stdin only when there are no files specified. `cat /dev/null -` will pipe contents of /dev/null and stdin to stdout.

As such `dd if=/dev/zero | cat /dev/null` apart from wasting a process differs in nothing from `cat /dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on Cygwin and Ubuntu and got the correct result in Ubuntu. If I don't send a signal to `dd` it works on Cygwin. I'm going to say that's a bug.

When I did a `tee` to send the output to a file, it consisted of all zero bytes, but there were too many of them.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=5000000 count=200 | gzip -c | gzip -cd |  tee dd.out | wc -c
```